# is there an increment method in neo4j similar to mongodb's $inc?

Tags: neo4j

I have a points property in a node that I'd like to increment every time a player receives points.  Since more than one update can come in simultaneously I'd like to have an increment update query to avoid concurrency issues. e.g. if two requests simultaneously fetched the node and updated the points by +5 each, it would increment by +5 rather than the correct +10.

I see that there was a closed issue #768 in github related to this, https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues/768, but I didn't see there was an answer other than implementing optimistic concurrency or a single queue on the application side.

If optimistic concurrency is the answer, maybe there is something at the database level that I can leverage?

Comment: New github issues are in neo4j/neo4j fyi. Apparently this transactional update will probably work out of the box in released 1.9, which isn't super far away. Also, int + int = int in the latest Cypher. (Previously it returned a double, which was annoying) Since I'm not answering your actual question, throwing this into a comment.

Comment: just wondering (as I have the same issue)... did this (in-situ update of property, free of concurrency issues, via cypher)  make it into 1.9M03?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to lock the node before reading, like so:

```
Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
try
{
    tx.acquireWriteLock( myNode );
    int count = (Integer) myNode.getProperty( "count", 0 );
    myNode.setProperty( "count", count + 5 );
    tx.success();
}
finally
{
    tx.finish();
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that I'd be using the REST api

Comment: no, REST is inherently non-transactional. For some TX support, please use the REST Batch API which will do one transaction for every batch request, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-batch-ops.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the github issue that I filed asking for this (the github repo has moved.)  But, the answer then was that this would not be added to the REST API.